# Webdriver - Xpath for URL embedded in Image

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to automate upload profile pic for employee feature.
However, the upload button shows up after clicking on employee photo image, which is a URL embedded in image

```
<div id="profile-pic">

<h1>fg gh</h1>
  <div class="imageHolder">

  <a href="/orangehrm-3.2.1/orangehrm-3.2.1/symfony/web/index.php/pim/viewPhotograph/empNumber/0065" class="tiptip">

    <img alt="Employee Photo" src="/orangehrm-3.2.1/orangehrm-3.2.1/symfony/web/index.php/pim/viewPhoto/empNumber/0065" border="0" id="empPic" width="200" height="200">
  </a>

  </div>    
</div>
```

Here is the snippet for which where in the employee link is dynamic.
It is appended with each employee ID.

Can you please help with the Xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the employee number you can have it as `//img[contains(@src,'0065')]` else `//div[@id='profile-pic']/img`